# Empty DataGridView bound to .sdf datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have bound a DataGridView to a .sdf file via a DataSet, using the VisualStudio UI.

I can preview the data in the dataset just fine, but when I load the application, the datagrid is empty.

Also, if I try to add columns to the datagrid, I can only add unbound columns; the "Databound column" option is disabled.

I have tried setting `dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true`, but that didn't help.

Code generated by the VS designer:

```
        // 
        // dgv
        // 
        this.dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgv.DataSource = this.bibliotecaDataSet;
        this.dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.dgv.Name = "dgv";
        this.dgv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(413, 230);
        this.dgv.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // bibliotecaDataSet
        // 
        this.bibliotecaDataSet.DataSetName = "BibliotecaDataSet";
        this.bibliotecaDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
        // 
        // bibliotecaDataSetBindingSource
        // 
        this.bibliotecaDataSetBindingSource.AllowNew = true;
        this.bibliotecaDataSetBindingSource.DataSource = this.bibliotecaDataSet;
        this.bibliotecaDataSetBindingSource.Position = 0;
```

Do I need some additional code in my main application class to fill the grid or what?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually:

1. Add empty DataGridView to form.
2. Create dataset.
3. Drag a specific table from the dataset panel into the DataGridView.